# Does this question belong on this site instead of Politics.SE?

Tags: discussion

Just came across this question:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23605/when-a-government-pays-centuries-old-debt-who-exactly-is-it-paying

Apart from the word 'government', this question doesn't seem related to politics at all. It'd be better answered by someone who has good financial knowledge, as indicated by the answer.

Posting here as I don't have the membership of Politics.SE, and have no intention of creating one for just this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more apt on economics site than this one. If posted, this question would have got closed here.

Comment: OK, thanks. Previously I was in the notion that this site is about money in general.

Answer (score 6):

A question should only be migrated if it's

1. A good question in general
2. On-topic on the target site
3. Off-topic on the original site or the poster requests migration

It's really for the politics site to decide whether it's off-topic for them, but either way it doesn't feel like a great question for here as it's not really a question about anyone's personal finances.